# How to replace links using lxml and iterlinks

Tags: python, lxml

I'm new to lxml and I'm trying to figure how to rewrite links using iterlinks().

```
import lxml.html
html = lxml.html.document_fromstring(doc)
for element, attribute, link, pos in html.iterlinks():
    if attibute == "src":
         link = link.replace('foo', 'bar')
print lxml.html.tostring(html)
```

However, this doesn't actually replace the links. I know I can use .rewrite_links, but iterlinks provides more information about each link, so I would prefer to use this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's not a good idea to name your variable `html` when you are importing a module named `html`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of just assigning a new (string) value to the variable name `link`, you have to alter the element itself, in this case by setting its `src` attribute:

```
new_src = link.replace('foo', 'bar') # or element.get('src').replace('foo', 'bar')
element.set('src', new_src)
```

Note that - if you know which "links" you are interested in, for example, only `img` elements - you can also get the elements by using `.findall()` (or xpath or css selectors) instead of using `.iterlinks()`.

Answer (score 1):

lxml provides a `rewrite_links` method (or function that you pass the text to be parsed into a document) to provide a method of changing all links in a document:

> .rewrite_links(link_repl_func, resolve_base_href=True, base_href=None):
>   This rewrites all the links in the document using your given link replacement function. If you give a base_href value, all links will be passed in after they are joined with this URL.
>   For each link link_repl_func(link) is called. That function then returns the new link, or None to remove the attribute or tag that contains the link. Note that all links will be passed in, including links like "#anchor" (which is purely internal), and things like "mailto:bob@example.com" (or javascript:...).

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code with rewrite_links:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring, tostring

e = fromstring("<html><body><a href='http://localhost'>hello</body></html>")

def my_rewriter(link):
  return "http://newlink.com"

e.rewrite_links(my_rewriter)
print(tostring(e))
```

Output:

```
    b'<html><body><a href="http://newlink.com">hello</a></body></html>'
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably link is just a copy of the actual object. Try replacing the attribute of the element in your loop. Even element can be just a copy, but it deserves a try...